# Are radio waves naturally produced?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, radio-frequency

I am just wondering if radio waves are naturally produced. If so how?

Comment: Switch on your AM radio set (if you still have one in this digital age, otherwise ask your father), tune it to where there is no broadcast signal and listen if there is a thunderstorm somewhere in the distance.

Answer (score 5):

radio waves of various wavelengths are produced by processes on earth (lightning bolts), in the sun (interactions between charged particle movement and magnetic fields), in some gas giant planets like jupiter (lightning bolts again), and in the cores of active galaxies (synchrotron radiation and other modes).

Naturally-occurring radio waves furnish the basis of *radioastronomy* and there are *radio telescopes* all around the world that are used to map the cosmos in radio frequencies. A search on these terms will return lots of information on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

Lightnings produce low frequency radio waves.

From [Wikipedia: Whistler (radio)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whistler_(radio)):

> A whistler is a very low frequency or VLF electromagnetic (radio) wave generated by lightning.
>   Frequencies of terrestrial whistlers are 1 kHz to 30 kHz,
>   with a maximum amplitude usually at 3 kHz to 5 kHz.
>   [...]
>   They are produced by lightning strikes (mostly intracloud and return-path)
>   where the impulse travels along the Earth's magnetic field lines
>   from one hemisphere to the other.
>   [...]